# Autofac register filter for multiple controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have 2 base controllers:

```
public class FirstBaseController : ApiController {}
public class SecondBaseController : ODataController {}
```

I also have a global filter for debugging purposes and I need to do property injection to pass in log4net.

I tried registering the filter for both controllers by doing:

```
builder.RegisterType<DebugAttribute>()
  .AsWebApiFilterFor<FirstBaseController>()
  .AsWebApiFilterFor<SecondBaseController>()
  .InstancePerRequest()
  .PropertiesAutowired();
```

The above code compiles but results in a runtime error. Currently I can only register a filter for one controller:

```
builder.RegisterType<DebugAttribute>()
  .AsWebApiFilterFor<FirstBaseController>()
  .InstancePerRequest()
  .PropertiesAutowired();
```

Is there a way to register one filter for multiple controllers for example adding a predicate like:

```
  .Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Base"))
```

Comment: Can you expand on what the issue is? Did you try the same thing and have it fail? Does `FirstBaseController` derive from `SecondBaseController` or vice-versa? Are you trying to use derived controllers and registering the filter on a base controller? A vanilla scenario like this should work.

Comment: I have two seperate base controllers and I want to register the filter for both of them.

Comment: Please add that to your question. Please include at least the class signatures. Please show the code you used to try to register the filter for the second controller. Please include an explanation of what you saw working (or not working) when you tried it.

Comment: Hi, did you find out anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can register filter separetly for every controller that you need.

```
builder.RegisterType<DebugAttribute>()
.AsWebApiFilterFor<FirstBaseController>()
.InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterType<DebugAttribute>()
.AsWebApiFilterFor<SecondBaseController>()
.InstancePerRequest();
```

But I think there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and I found on AutoFac Github page that this problem is defined as a bug. We can't register a filter for several Controllers at the same time.
**This bug is still open (feb 2017)**.

@Rroman gave the solution:
Actually you have to use multiple declaration statements to register filters for each controllers.

[Autofac github page - Bug declaration](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi/issues/17)